# Load Hidden DIVs Last or OnMouseClick

Tags: jquery, html, css, load, hidden

www.prismasites.com

I am making a world map with DIV's shaped like Continents using SVG.

When I click on a continent on the world map - it hides the world map DIV and shows the continent DIV with SVG.

I have already accomplished this.

However

Each continent SVG is contained within .php file

The .php file is loaded and placed inside hidden DIVs.

Like so

```
<div id="TestimonialsMap">
<?php locate_template( array( 'worldmap.php', 'worldmap.php', 'worldmap.php' ), true, false ); ?>
</div>
<div id="TestimonialsMapNorthAmerica" style="display:none;">
<?php locate_template( array( 'WorldMapNorthAmerica.php', 'WorldMapNorthAmerica.php', 'WorldMapNorthAmerica.php' ), true, false ); ?>
</div>
<div id="TestimonialsMapSouthAmerica"  style="display:none;">
<?php locate_template( array( 'WorldMapSouthAmerica.php', 'WorldMapSouthAmerica.php', 'WorldMapSouthAmerica.php' ), true, false ); ?>
</div>
<div id="TestimonialsMapEurope" style="display:none;">
<?php locate_template( array( 'WorldMapEurope.php', 'WorldMapEurope.php', 'WorldMapEurope.php' ), true, false ); ?>
</div>
<div id="TestimonialsMapAfrica" style="display:none;">
<?php locate_template( array( 'WorldMapAfrica.php', 'WorldMapAfrica.php', 'WorldMapAfrica.php' ), true, false ); ?>
</div>
<div id="TestimonialsMapMiddleEast" style="display:none;">
<?php locate_template( array( 'WorldMapMiddleEast.php', 'WorldMapMiddleEast.php', 'WorldMapMiddleEast.php' ), true, false ); ?>
</div>
<div id="TestimonialsMapAsia" style="display:none;">
<?php locate_template( array( 'WorldMapAsia.php', 'WorldMapAsia.php', 'WorldMapAsia.php' ), true, false ); ?>
</div>
<div id="TestimonialsMapOceania" style="display:none;">
<?php locate_template( array( 'WorldMapOceania.php', 'WorldMapOceania.php', 'WorldMapOceania.php' ), true, false ); ?>
</div>
```

THE PROBLEM:

The Browser loads All DIVs in Sequential Layout Order.

INCLUDING Hidden DIV's

So like...

> 1. Load Task #1: [basic div] --- Loaded
> 2. Load Task #2: {Crazy Large Hidden SVG Div} --- loading 45% for the past 1 minute
> 3. Load Task #3: [basic div] --- In queue [ not loaded yet ].
> 4. Load Task #4: [basic div] --- In queue [ not loaded yet ].

Hidden DIV's still load All Continent SVG's

All Continent SVG's are HUGE Vector Files

They take a LONG TIME to load.

www.prismasites.com

When the page loads
It loads up okay until Testimonials

There it stops and goes invisible
To load all of the hidden DIVs.

Here it stops loading all the other DIVs

Here it takes 1 minute to load all hidden DIVs

Which is a slow retarded way to load a website.

Because it should load all small basic box DIV's that have a smaller size which load faster FIRST

And it should load HIDDEN Complex Custom Shaped DIV's that have a larger size which load slower LAST

I want it to load the DIV's in my FAQ Section and Contact Sections BEFORE it loads all my hidden DIVs in my Testimonial's Section.

So instead of this

> Load Task #1: [basic div] --- Loaded
>
> Load Task #2: {Crazy Large Hidden SVG Div} --- loading 45% for the past 1 minute
>
> Load Task #3: [basic div] --- In queue [ not loaded yet ].
>
> Load Task #4: [basic div] --- In queue [ not loaded yet ].

I want this

> Load Task #1: [basic div] --- Loaded
>
> Load Task #4: {Crazy Large Hidden SVG Div} --- loading 45% for the past 1 minute
>
> Load Task #3: [basic div] --- loaded.
>
> Load Task #2: [basic div] --- loaded.

---

So using Jquery / Javascript

How can I have it so that my webpage does not load hidden DIV's on start up?

How can I have it so that the browser loads hidden DIV's LAST?

OR

How can I have it so that the browser loads hidden DIV's only on mouseclick?

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  
  document.getElementById("complex").innerHTML="COMPLEX STUFF HERE"
 };

function clickme(e){

e.innerHTML="your stuff is now loading blah blagh";
};
```

```css
img{max-width:100px;max-height:100px;}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />

<div id="complex">
  <img src="http://ppt4web.ru/assets/2c736062/img/loading.gif" alt="loading"  />

</div>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/700/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/200/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/444/344/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/604/350/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/408/366/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/320/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/340/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/999/306/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/998/306/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/976/306/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/996/306/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/985/306/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/974/306/" alt="Lorem Pixel" />

<h2>OR</h2>

<div onclick="clickme(this)">Click me</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to paste in "COMPLEX STUFF HERE"